# Simple NUnit test fail because exception is not thrown ( out of the test is thrown)

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm creating an extension generic method Apply, what it does is not important, the major problem is that I cant understand how to test it, a simple test like ApplyOnNullFunctionThrow fail to say that no exception is thrown, but if I run a "manual test" from main it throws

The main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var i in first.Apply(second,f)) Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The extension method:

```
public static class Applier
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Apply<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second,Func<T,T,T> f)
    {
        if(f == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (null==first || null==second) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var x=second.GetEnumerator();
        
        foreach (var item in first)
        {
           yield return x.MoveNext() ? f(item, x.Current) : f(item, default);

        }

        while (x.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return f(default, x.Current);
        }
            

    }
}
```

The test:

```
class ApplierTests
{
    [TestCase(new[]{1,2,3},new[]{10,20,30},null)]
    public void ApplyOnNullFunctionThrow<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second,Func<T,T,T> f)
    {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => first.Apply(second, f));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Apply` method you have `yield` keyword which means that the elements of the sequence will be returned one at a time. So when you just call the method with `yield` keyword, under the hood it does nothing, but just returns an iterator (`IEnumerable<T>`) which you can use in, for example, `foreach`. The bottom line here is that the code of your original `Apply` method isn't executed until `MoveNext` is called on the iterator returned, therefore it doesn't throw the exception. To fix this you may want to have a wrapper which is without `yield` keyword:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Apply<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second,Func<T,T,T> f)
{
    if(f == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (null==first || null==second) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    return ApplyInternal(first, second, f);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> ApplyInternal<T>(...) {
    var x=second.GetEnumerator();
    
    foreach (var item in first)
    {
       yield return x.MoveNext() ? f(item, x.Current) : f(item, default);

    }

    while (x.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return f(default, x.Current);
    }
}
```

Instead of creating a private method you also can use [C# 7 feature called local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) as alternative

See also, the exception is thrown when you call the method in `Main`, because you use the result of the method in the `foreach` statement which is compiled into repeated calls to `MoveNext`.

Comment: I owe you a beer man, explained so clealry that I have understand how to fix some problems in 2 different projects for my last exam in university